# Convert List<String> to a xml-schema type (defined as lists of strings)

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, xsd, type-conversion

I have a class called `StringArray` and `StringStringArray` which are generated from XML-Schema files. The are defined like this:

```
 * &lt;complexType name="stringArray">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="item" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>

 * &lt;complexType name="stringArrayArray">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="item" type="{http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array}stringArray" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
```

The classes are defined in the following way (classes are provided by the instructors of an exercise course):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "stringArray", propOrder = {
    "item"
})
public class StringArray {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<String> item;

    public List<String> getItem() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "stringArrayArray", propOrder = {
    "item"
})
public class StringArrayArray {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<StringArray> item;

    public List<StringArray> getItem() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<StringArray>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }
}
```

Now I need to add an object of type `List<String>` to an `StringStringArray` object. The situation looks like this:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
StringArrayArray respond = new StringArrayArray();

ListIterator<List<String>> listIterator = listOfLists.listIterator();
while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
    int index = listIterator.nextIndex();
    List<String> key = listIterator.next();
    respond.getItem().add((StringArray) key); // fails with runtime cast error
}
```

The `add` method of the `StringStringArray` object wants a `StringArray`. I also need the `addAll` method with the expected parameter `Collection<? extends StringArray> arg`.
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
With a convert function it works fine, but I'm not sure whether thats a "good" solution.

```
private StringArray convert(List<String> list) {
    StringArray array = new StringArray();
    for (String string : list) {
        array.getItem().add(string);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Meiner.

Comment: Please add code. What does the `StringArray` class look like? Is it part of a public API? Can you link its javadoc?

Comment: I changed the whole post, it was poorly written.